# How to check if the value stored in a variable is integer or not in c. For example, we have something like Integer.tryparse in C#, something like that

Tags: c

I want to check if the value stored in a float type variable is actually an integer, so that i can cast it to an integer type without losing data precision.

my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>

int main

{

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    double i = log(n);
    while( i is not an integer)
    {
        printf("\n Enter another number");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        i = log(n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have a hard time finding an integer whose `log` is also an integer. Perhaps you meant log2?

Comment: @rici: there at least the trivial log(1) = 0...

Comment: @SergeBallesta: True enough. Now find another one :)

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Answering my own challenge, if you allow longs (and not just ints, as in the above program), then log(214643579785916) is so close to 33 that a standard library implementation might return exactly 33.

Comment: @Saurav Mukherjee. Do you want to know if the log of an integer is an integer (as in your example)?. There is a very small range of double values that are the log of an intered compared to full range of doubles. Or do you want to know if a value stored in a double, regardless of how it has been obtained or what rounding errors might have suffered, is an exact integeger? I suspect it is the later. For your particular code, if int is 32 bits, you could just check i!=0.0 since that is the only possible integer as rice and Serge have shown.

Comment: In my program i am going for log 2, so what i want is to check for integer values when user enters 4, 8, 16 and so on.

Comment: @suarav: if your problem is "how to tell whether an integer is a power of 2", there is a much simpler solution which does not require complicated numerical approximations. Hint: what are the binary representations of x and x-1?

Answer (score 3):

> ... to check if the value stored in a float type variable is actually an integer ...

Use 2 tests.

1) Test if `float value` has an fractional part:  "The `modf` functions break the argument value into integral and fractional parts, each of which has the same type and sign as the argument."  This is sufficient to test if the a floating point value is a whole number.  Note: use `modf()` for `double`

```
    #include <math.h>
    float ipart;
    float frac = modff(value, &ipart);
    if (!(frac == 0.0f)) puts("Not a whole number").
```

2) If also converting to an integer type, test if the `value` is in range of the desired type before converting:

```
    #include <limits.h>
    if (value < INT_MIN*1.0 || value > INT_MAX*1.0) puts("Outside `int` range").
    int y = (int) value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    double i = log(n);
    while(!(i == (int)i))
    {
        printf("\n Enter another number");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        i = log(n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works, atleast for me, but again i am facing a very awkward problem in the context. So, i cant close the topic yet. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with floating point numbers is that they're not completely accurate. If you try dividing 10 by 9 in the decimal system, you'll end up with a value that has an infinite number of 1s. A floating point number has the same issue (except that your computer works in base 2 rather than 10, but that's really a detail). Since you can't describe an infinite number of ones to a computer, that means you'll have some rounding in your result. As such, if you do a complex calculation that involves more than one operation your 'integer' isn't going to be one in some cases, even though if you were to calculate it by hand it would be.

If what you're trying to do is figure out whether the result of a particular calculation on an floating point value yields an integer value, a better approach is to do a check with the reverted algorithm on a rounded value; that is, in this case, perform the `log()` of the input, round the result, and feed it to the `pow()` function with the appropriate arguments. If the result of that `pow()` is your input again, you're good.

Comment: The inverse of `log` is `exp` (in C, anyway) and the roundtrip might not be exact, either. (As mentioned in a comment in the question, there are very few integers such that the approximation to the natural logarithm of the integer as computed by the standard library also happens to be an integer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the modulus of 1.

```
while( fmod(i,1) != 0)
```

Or rather with thresholds

```
int is_integer(double d, double threshold)
{
    return d < threshold && d > -threshold;
}
```

Example how to call

```
while(!is_integer(x, 1e-6))
```

Answer (score -2):

Check if the value not [isfinite](http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/math.h/isfinite.htm) or the difference between it and its cast to long is different than zero.
This does not work for doubles with a value too large as it is not representable as a long. But all finite double values greater than 2^52 or lower than -(2^52) are always integer so there is no need to check those.

```
!isfinite(i) || (i>-4503599627370496.0 && i<4503599627370496.0 && ((long)i)-i != 0 )
```

Previous expresion returns true if `i` is not an integer.

This only works for an architecture where `long` is at least 53 bits long though.

For compilers supporting `long long` that is a type guaranteed to have at least 64 bits so this would work regardless of architecture :

```
!isfinite(i) || (i>-4503599627370496.0 && i<4503599627370496.0 && ((long long)i)-i != 0 )
```

Comment: This is OK except the `long(i)-i != 0` part.  Consider 32-bit `long`.  Certainly `long(4503599627370496.0/2)` is UB.  `long long` or `intmax_t` would be better.  Yet C does not specify even that would work.

Comment: True, I can't assume long will be 64 bits.

Comment: `long long` should always work since it is always at least 64 bits. And only integers between -2^52 and 2^52 would ever be casted to `long long` due to shortcircuit evaluation of &&.   4503599627370496.0 = 2^52

Comment: Agree `long long` is always at least 63-bits and sign.  Do not agree that `double` precision should always be <= 63 bits.  `double` must be at least 34 bits precision (plus signed and exponent) and _commonly_ has 53 bit precision.

Answer (score -5):

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
double i = log(n);
while( i-int(i) !=0 )
{
    printf("\n Enter another number");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    i = log(n);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Unless there is a good reason to believe that the floating point number is *exactly* an integer, it would probably be a good idea to accept numbers *very close* to integers, for some definition of "very close". (Not my downvote, but I'm guessing that could have been the objection.)

Comment: Maybe the downvote is because that code will not work with double values which fall outside of the integer range. Like 2^33